# TYPO3 Indexed search showing wrong pagination

Tags: typo3, typoscript, extbase

I have an indexed search engine configured with TYPO3 site.

It shows the search results, but with wrong pagination. After selecting other pages except the first one, it shows correct pagination.First page shows 129 results

> page1 page2 page3 page4.... page10 Next>>

but we r going to page 10 the page is empty and the results showig total of 19 results

> page1 page2 Next >>

```
page.config.index_enable = 1
page.config.index_externals = 0

lib.topsearchbar = COA
lib.topsearchbar {
  10 = TEXT
  10.typolink.parameter = 101
  10.typolink.returnLast = url
  10.wrap = <form action="|" autocomplete="off" method="post" class="search-form"><fieldset><div class="form-group has-feedback">
  20 = COA
  20 {
    10 = TEXT
    10.data = GPvar : tx_indexedsearch |sword
    10.wrap ( 
      <input type="search" id="search" class="form-control search-input" name="tx_indexedsearch[sword]"  placeholder="search" />
      <span class="ion-android-search search-open-btn"></span>

    )
    20 = COA
    20 {
      10 = TEXT
      10.value = <input type="hidden" name="tx_indexedsearch[sections]" value="0" />
      15 = TEXT
      15.value = <input type="hidden" name="tx_indexedsearch[lang]" value="0" />
    }
  }
  wrap = | </div></fieldset></form>
}
[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
lib.topsearchbar.20.20.15.value = <input type="hidden" name="tx_indexedsearch[lang]" value="1" />
[global]

plugin.tx_indexedsearch.settings.displayAdvancedSearchLink = 0
plugin.tx_indexedsearch.settings.displayLevel1Sections = 0
plugin.tx_indexedsearch.settings.clearSearchBox = 1
```

Comment: Which versions do you use by the way ??

Comment: Can you be more explicit in what is "wrong pagination"? Links are broken? Less/more pages, than needed? Doesn't correlate with search results?

Comment: @ViktorLivakivskyi I edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible issue can be in access-restricted pages, which are not taken into account by default.

From [indexed_search manual](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/indexed_search/latest/Configuration/TypoScript/Index.html#search-exactcount):

> **search.exactCount**
>
> Force permission check for every record while displaying search
>   results. Otherwise, records are only checked up to the current result
>   page, and this might cause that the result counter does not print the
>   exact number of search hits.
>
> By enabling this setting, the loop is not stopped, which causes an
>   exact result count at the cost of an (obvious) slowdown caused by this
>   overhead.

So, you can simply set `plugin.tx_indexedsearch.search.exactCount = 1` to solve this issue.

Answer (score -2):

In typo3 9 it is plugin.tx_indexedsearch.settings.exactCount = 1

Comment: Exactly the same solution as in the accepted answer.

Comment: You can check with plugin configuration, plugin.tx_indexedsearch.settings.exactCount = 1 is working for me